# PySide - resetting the mainwindow central widget from within the central widget

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyside

I'm trying to create a GUI window which opens with a central widget showing several options to choose from. Each option replaces the central widget with a new window based on the users choice. Similar to how programmes like PyCharm and QtDesigner open up.

Currently I'm unable to make this work. This is what I've tried:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class ControlMainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, Widg = Opener()):
        super(ControlMainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.widget = Widg
        self.widget.setupUi(self)
        if isinstance(Widg, Opener):
            print(1)
            QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), MainWidgetChange(parent, widg=StatementView()))
        print(2)


class ControlMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ControlMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

def MainWidgetChange(Window, widg = Opener()):
    the_widget = ControlMainWidget(parent = Window, Widg = widg)

    Window.setCentralWidget(the_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mySW = ControlMainWindow()
    MainWidgetChange(mySW)
    mySW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Opener and StatementView are classes made using qtDesigner so are a bit wordy. I'll include Opener, but StatementView is ~250 lines so I'll leave that out of here.

```
class Opener(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(450, 400)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(450, 400))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(450, 400))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.toolButton = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_2 = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_3 = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
        self.toolButton_3.setObjectName("toolButton_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.toolButton_4 = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
        self.toolButton_4.setObjectName("toolButton_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tables", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Graphs", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Statements", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolButton_4.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Modelling", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

At the moment the window loads with Opener as the central widget - I can also hard code it to set StatementView as the central widget without errors.

However when I use the above functions, when clicking on the toolbutton in opener, nothing happens. I've tried to replace this line:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), MainWidgetChange(parent, widg=StatementView()))`

with

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), MainWidgetChange(self.parent, widg=StatementView()))`

Which throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/Statements/New test code/mainui2.py", line 593, in <module>
    MainWidgetChange(mySW)
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/Statements/New test code/mainui2.py", line 586, in MainWidgetChange
    the_widget = ControlMainWidget(parent = Window, Widg = widg)
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/Statements/New test code/mainui2.py", line 575, in __init__
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), MainWidgetChange(self.parent, widg=StatementView()))
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/Statements/New test code/mainui2.py", line 586, in MainWidgetChange
    the_widget = ControlMainWidget(parent = Window, Widg = widg)
  File "/home/milo/Documents/Codes/Statements/New test code/mainui2.py", line 570, in __init__
    super(ControlMainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QWidget(builtin_function_or_method)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget = None, PySide.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags = 0)
```

and fails to load the main window.

So is there a standard way of doing this which I'm missing? I'm not sure what else to try at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I forgot that connect events should use functions as objects (as in not with the brackets/arguments) - I encased the function in the connect event within a lambda. All works now.

So:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), MainWidgetChange(parent, widg=StatementView()))`

To:

`QtCore.QObject.connect(self.widget.toolButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), lambda: MainWidgetChange(parent, widg=StatementView()))`